# how to make headers in android with text and buttons like in iOS

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

i want to create header in android with text and buttons like in iOS (Text in Cetner and Buttons on right and left side), i have tried but not useful at all,please guide me ... how can i make this one for my app

Answer (score 5):

Try this. Make header.xml file and put below code in it and use it in any layout file using `include` .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:background="@drawable/titlebar"
    android:gravity="center">

     <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/back_button"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5.0dip"
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonBack"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ui_image_home_description"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textViewTitleBar"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        style="@style/TitleBarText"
        android:singleLine="false"/>


    <ImageButton 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/home_button"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_marginRight="5.0dip"
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonHome"
        android:contentDescription="@string/ui_image_home_description"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Note : Add the below style to style.xml in res/values folder.

```
 <style name="TitleBarText">
        <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
        <item name="android:textSize"> 17sp </item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">12dip</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">12dip</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
        <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: nice brother, you have done 90% work of mine, but still there is an issue, i need to show these buttons over textview, please help i am trying to get that..thanks

Comment: can you please provide me any screen shot or wirefram ?

Comment: please browse this url:- http://mobileorchard.com/ios-development-tutorial-series-tableviews/   like:- podcast header with button

Comment: @user1369219 this code works as you want . Make first imageview's visibility GONE.

Comment: please set android:text="Test" to your textview and see what happns . You can also set text in activity also.

Comment: Thanks for support, but fact is your textview starts after lefthand side image and ends before righthand side image .... anyways thank you

Comment: Ok brother,but by use of below xml code i have achieved my target, thanks again....

Answer (score 2):

This is an easier one. You can try this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        android:background="@drawable/header">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Back" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Next" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks kittu88, i have achieved my target by your code, and can i ask one more question?

Comment: @user1369219 surely you can

Comment: @user1369219 if the answer really helped you then please accept it