# android add a button to an header (iOS look)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

Hey I am trying to create a header with an image in the center and a button at the right corner.

I found this post [how to make headers in android with text and buttons like in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12815993/how-to-make-headers-in-android-with-text-and-buttons-like-in-ios), and the following tutorial http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-custom-window-title-in-android/ , and I was able to put the image in the center and set the background. However, no matter what I do my button won't show up at the right corner.

I tried to see if it was masked by the background or maybe out of the screen, but I could not find the reason for my problem.

my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Header"
            android:src="@drawable/header"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ff000000"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

                <Button
            android:id="@+id/lockButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5.0dip"        
            android:text="TEST"
            />


    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think it would be better to use ActionBar: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Comment: the problem is your linearlayout has a center gravity

Comment: If i need to support 2.3 and up can I still use the action bar? cause I understood that it is only for 3 and up

Comment: You can use ActionBarSherlock (http://actionbarsherlock.com/) to get action bar on Android 2.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not `relative`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/img_vs_navbar" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_back"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_setting_back" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

You can put it in center by using `android:layout_centerInParent` like this.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/img_vs_navbar" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_setting_back" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Or use `alignParentRight` to put it at right

Edited :

This one is for using two imageview in one xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/img_vs_navbar" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_setting_back" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_setting_back" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what is the added value of using relative over linear?

Comment: You can customize u'r header as much as u want.

Comment: also would you define both in the same xml? or do you need to separate xmls?

Comment: Just updated the answer with new xml which use two imageview. Hope this will help

Comment: Yes is does, one quick question I tried to limit the size of one of my images because it is too big by doing :width="30dp" but this does not seems to work, any idea if this is a relative layout issue?

Comment: 9patch is a good way to solve this type of problem. http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="#ff000000"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/header" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/lockButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5.0dip"
        android:text="TEST" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: hey , this would work, the issue is my image is too big and overlap with the button. I think scaling it will do

Answer (score 0):

Because your ImageView has a fill_parent width, you'll need to add a weight attribute to it.

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

If you want it to span the whole row, you could use change your LinearLayout to be a RelativeLayout.